# Assign NA to cells according to sum of column and row index for each cell

Tags: r, for-loop, dataframe, nested-loops

I am dealing with a data frame and should assign `NA` values in cells, if sum of the row and column index for each cell bigger than a certain value.

```
df <- matrix(data = rnorm(n = 40, mean = 0, sd = 1), nrow = 5, ncol = 8)
```

I can do it, with a nested for_loop, but it is too slow for the big datasets.

Here is my solution

```
for (i in 1 : ncol(df)){
  for (j in 1 : nrow(df)){
    if ( i + j > 10){
      df[j, i] <- NA
    }
  }
}
```

It does mean if the sum of column and row index is bigger than 10, `NA` should be assigned in these cells.

If somebody can another faster way from mine, it would be great.

Comment: `df[col(df) + row(df) > 10] <- NA`